# How to pass MVC3 Model as JSON param to JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following input button:

```
<input type="button" value="Log On" onclick="TryLogon(@Model)" style=" height:25px; width:75px"/>
```

And I want to pass the Model as a JSON param to the TryLogon function:

```
function TryLogon(model) {

    $.getJSON("/CertificateWebSite/Account/LogOnHelper", model, OnLogonResult);

}
```

How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Model` won't be bound to anything that didn't exist on the initial page load.

Try changing how you're doing your log on click and what is being passed:

```
<input type="button" value="Log On" id="logOnButton" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#logOnButton").click(function(){
            var data = { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() };
            $.getJSON("/CertificateWebSite/Account/LogOnHelper", data, OnLogonResult);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Also you can use jQuery's [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method so you don't need to explicitly call out each input in the form.